# Is there a need for "how" here

Tags: grammar

> Some people believe that children should learn **how** to be
>   respectable members of society from their parents.

**Would there be a grammatical problem if "how" was omitted?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a grammatical problem, but a change of meaning.

> Some people believe that children should learn **how** to be respectable members of society from their parents.

This means that the parents should tech their children the **method** of being respectable - the things that they must do to achieve this goal Whereas

> Some people believe that children should learn **to be** respectable members of society from their parents.

means that parents should insure that children become respectable, perhaps by force of example. They might or might not learn methods that achieve this result, or they might simply acquire habits without consciously understanding them. This is a subtle difference in meaning, but sometimes it could be significant.